# Spring Eclipselink Dynamic session property

Tags: spring, eclipselink

I need to use @AdditionalCriteria Annotation for my entities to isolate data depending on the logged in user "userPrinicpal"

I added the following for each Entity:

```
@AdditionalCriteria("this.owner = :owner")
```

the problem is: I do not know how to map :owner parameter to the current logged in user, I tried mapping it using SessionCustomizer, but I figured out that SessionCustomizer executed at Application Start up time and not for each session.

anyone has an idea on how to achieve this ?

Kind Regards,
Razi

Answer (score 0):

Did you try,

em.setProperty("owner", theOwner)

You could also pass the "owner" property in your persistence unit properties, or set it on the emf.

Comment: I know I can create this, but that means that I need to set this property in each DAO "@Repository" class, and even more, I need to set it in each method of DAO classes because these classes are initialized at application startup, am I right ?

Comment: Thanks @James.
I ended up creating a SessionEventListener class and added eclipselink.session-event-listener property to emf bean config. it works fine. but still it executed before each sql statement because I used postAcquireConnection function. is there a way to tell spring or eclipselink to not release the connection after each sql statement ?